# What PHP library/class could I use to read/write Excel file(s)

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I am looking for a php library which supports accepting an excel file (like .xls or .xlsx) and then some sort of functionality to create an array populated with values of each column. (Separate arrays).

I know there might not be a read to use solution thus I thought about programming it. However, I was wondering which library could I use for several scenarios?

The few I cam across were

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

I have no idea which one use, though codeplex one seems to be most functional, but I don't want to use a too heavy php library and then not end up using 90% of the code.

Also depending of the framework which one could fit better?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel and http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ are the same library; and it's the one I'd recommend (though I do have a bias as the developer)

Comment: I found spout library which is easy to use and fast generating, reading Excel files, a lot of features.. https://github.com/box/spout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**PHPExcel** is the great library. I prefer to use it!

You can also take a look an example of this library on CodeIgniter [here](http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework)

Comment: Note that PHPExcel is not usable with large files, because it then very slow and uses sevaral GB of memory.

Comment: PHPExcel development has ceased – the rewrite (dropping compatibility for codebase quality) is to be found in the https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet project

Answer (score 2):

I use PHPExcel at codeplex! They have great support there! Also it is very lightweight and has great documentation!